# How to fix Huawei P30 "Getting Package info Failed Error"?

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking, huawei, android-10

I am trying to fix my Huawei P30 (Android 10) which gets stuck in recovery mode. I tried to fix it by using eRecovery but I get the error "Get Package info failed".

Around the internet, I was told to flash a new ROM to solve this problem, but there is no tutorial for flashing stock ROMs for Huawei P30 on the internet. My Huawei P30 does not have an SD Card slot meaning I can't use the method of adding `update.app` to `/dload` folder on an SD card.

I also cannot use ADB fastboot because the Huawei on Android 10 does not have the image files required (`boot.img`, `recovery.img`, etc.) Instead, it has a myriad of images like `Super.img`, `Ramdisk.img`, `erocovery.img`, etc. I don't know which ones to select because I am unable to find a tutorial on the internet that tells me which files to select.

I also cannot use the SP Flash Tool because Android 10 stock ROMs do not have scatter file XML or txt (it has `update.app`)

I am unable to use SigmaKey as well because of the "SmartCard resource manager not running" error (I'm on Windows 10)

I have exhausted many options with no luck, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the volume up button and put the charger in. When it turns on, release it, reset it, type yes, scroll up with the volume button, press the on and off button after scrolling down with the volume down button. After that, go to reboot.